# How to get the closed form solution of a non-convex optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to know if there is a closed form expression for the optimal objective function? How can I get it, if it does exist?

Condition: $h,f\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times1}, \epsilon > 0 $.

$\max \ \ e^Hhh^He + (f^Hhh^H-h^H)e + e^H(hh^Hf-h)  \\ s.t.\ \ e^He \leq \epsilon^2   $

Comment: are $h$ and $f$ given?

Comment: yes, $h$ and $f$ are given.

Comment: Actually, this problem is a  Trust Region Subproblem (TRS). Generally, TRS has no closed form solution, but here it is a very simple situation. So I want to know whether I can get one closed form solution

Comment: it is indeed a convex optimization problem. Did you try using the KKT conditions?

Comment: It is not that difficult to recast this problem in real domain and make the norm constraint as $e^Te\leq 1$. Once you can convince yourself with that, see this question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522267/find-the-real-vector-x-which-satisfies-all-this/522280?noredirect=1#522280

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. I was running out of space in comments. It is not difficult to recast your problem as 
\begin{align}
\max_{\mathbf{x}}&~\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{h}\mathbf{h}^T\mathbf{x}-\alpha \mathbf{h}^T\mathbf{x} \\\
&\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}\leq 1
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ is some suitable real constant. This is clearly a convex problem. The $\mathbf{h}$ in this is not same as the $\mathbf{h}$ given in your problem. $\mathbf{h}=[\mathbf{h}_R^T,\mathbf{h}_C^T]^T$ where $\mathbf{h}_R$ and $\mathbf{h}_C$ are the real and complex part of your original $\mathbf{h}$. Now applying KKT is bit easier. I have posted it as a question here. [Find the real vector $x$ which satisfies all this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522267/find-the-real-vector-x-which-satisfies-all-this/522280?noredirect=1#522280) . Any solution to that question should address your problem.

Comment: This is not a convex problem. It is convex, only if it is $\min$, not $\max$.

Comment: oops, I get it!!. You are familiar with semi-definite relaxation?

Comment: you can find this paper[http://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/10012/1038/1/c2fortin2000.pdf], it is useful

Comment: Thanks for your help, dineshdileep. You can google this paper <A survey of the trust region subproblem within a semidefinite framework>. It is very useful.

Comment: Actually, the question you posted is useful. because the optimal solution is on the boudary. the KKT conditions is the optimal condition, which is sufficient and necessary.

Comment: I don't understand how KKT conditions are sufficient and necessary. Can you point me to some reference.

Comment: Soryy. I did not say it correctly. You can google this thesis <Efficient Trust Region Subproblem Algorithms>, and see the page 10 of the paper