# Find the real vector $x$ which satisfies all this?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I got this after applying KKT conditions to an optimization problem. Let $\mathbf{h}$ be a given $N\times 1$  real vector. Let $\alpha$ be a real constant. We need to find $\lambda$ and the $N\times 1$ real vector $\mathbf{x}$ such that 
\begin{align}
(\mathbf{h}\mathbf{h}^T-\lambda\mathbf{I})\mathbf{x}&=\alpha\mathbf{h} \\\
\lambda &\geq 0\\\
\lambda(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}-1) &= 0 \\\
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}&\leq1
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

First equation implies that $$-\lambda {\bf x} =(-{\bf h}\cdot {\bf x}+ \alpha) {\bf h}$$

(1) $\lambda =0$ and ${\bf h}=0$ : Then ${\bf x}$ is any vector whose length is smaller than 1.

(2) $\lambda=0$ and ${\bf h}\neq 0$ : Then ${\bf h}\cdot {\bf x}= \alpha$.

So, $${\bf x} = \alpha \frac{{\bf h}}{|{\bf h}|^2} + {\bf w}$$ where $\forall\ {\bf w}\in {\bf h}^\perp$ such that $|{\bf w}|^2 + \alpha^2 \frac{1}{|{\bf h}|^2} \leq 1$.

(3) $\lambda \neq 0$ : Then note that ${\bf h}\neq 0$ : $\lambda ({\bf x}^T{\bf x} -1)=0$ implies that ${\bf x}$ has unit length. From $({\bf h}{\bf h}^T-\lambda {\bf I}){\bf x}=\alpha {\bf h}$, if ${\bf h}=0$, then $\lambda {\bf x} =0$. It is a contradiction.

And ${\bf x} =\frac{1}{\lambda}(-{\bf h}\cdot {\bf x}+ \alpha) {\bf h}$. This implies that ${\bf x}$ is a multiple of ${\bf h}$. So we conclude that $${\bf x}=\frac{{\bf h}}{|{\bf h}|},\ \lambda  =(-|{\bf h}|+ \alpha) |{\bf h}|.$$

Comment: in case 2:, shouldn't it be  $\frac{\alpha^2}{|\mathbf{h}|^2}+|\mathbf{w}|^2\leq 1$?

Comment: also case (3) have $\mathbf{x}$ on both sides of the eqn for $\mathbf{x}$

Comment: In (2), you're right. I miss a square. And in (3), ${\bf x} = \frac{1}{\lambda} (-{\bf h}\cdot {\bf x} + \alpha) {\bf h}$. Even though ${\bf x}$ appears in both side we can conclude that ${\bf x}$ is a multiple of ${\bf h}$ So ${\bf x} = {\bf h}/|{\bf h}|$ since it has unit length

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the assumption $\mathbf{h}\neq 0$, can you please rewrite the answer neatly, so that others don't have to read the comments to get the complete picture.